# How to read property as List<String> from [] in springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

Sometime i see somebody define like this in property file:

```java
spring.autoconfigure.exclude[0]=com.vietnam.AAutoConfiguration
spring.autoconfigure.exclude[1]=com.vietnam.BAutoConfiguration
```

just question: how to define a property in Spring bean to collect this config as list?
in other place they said to use like this:
in propery:

```java
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=com.vietnam.AAutoConfiguration,com.vietnam.BAutoConfiguration
```

in spring bean

```java
@Value("#{'${spring.autoconfigure.exclude}'.split(',')}"
```

But i dont like this way in case the value is long. one config per line would be easier to read and mantain

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found the way, use `@Value` will not support case i want.
We need to use `@ConfigurationProperties` then Spring will collect property as list

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.autoconfigure")
public class SpringConfig {
  @Setter //lombok
  private List<String> exclude;
}
```

Config will simple like:

```java
spring.autoconfigure.exclude[0]=com.vietnam.AAutoConfiguration
spring.autoconfigure.exclude[1]=com.vietnam.BAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read multiple strings like below
in application.properties

```
app.names=vipul,uncle,bob
```

in you component class

```
@Value("${app.names}")
private List<String> names;
```

Comment: sure it's fine if values are short texts. but i dont prefer using comma in some case of long value. not easy to maintain

Answer (score 0):

Lists may also be like this

```
app.names={'Baeldung','dot','com'}

app.names2={\
  'One long text example',\
  'Another long text example'\
  }
```

```java
@Value("#{${app.names}}")
private List<String> appNames;
```

Source https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-arrays-lists

Map example:

```
valuesMap={key1: '1', key2: '2', key3: '3'}
```

```java
@Value("#{${valuesMap}}")
private Map<String, Integer> valuesMap;
```

Source https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation